# Getting ACF field value in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, advanced-custom-fields

**I try to add a link to a file (uploaded in ACF field) in a Gravity form notification, in Wordpress.**

So, as given in Gravity form and ACF documentation, I tried in my functions.php to add a hook to the gravity form notification mail function :

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_1', 'my_gform_add_link', 10, 3 );
function my_gform_add_link( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
    $postID = intval($entry[2]); //return the ID of the post as an int
    $notification['message'] .= '\n <a href="'.get_field('spec-file', $postID).'">See this furniture specs</a>';

    return $notification;
}
```

In the code above : `$postID` works as expected (it returns the expected post ID). The thing is : `get_field('spec-file', $postID)` (which is the recommended method to get a field value outside the loop - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/) returns empty.

Why ? Any idea ?

EDIT : **The post ID wasn't correct**, I fixed it and the code above works as expected.

Comment: There's no more code related to my issue. I add a filter, and the function related to it. What do you want to see ?

Comment: yeah sorry, the edit sent too early. get_field() is when you want to set a variable. When running the result try the_field() ?

Comment: This is a filter function, I don't want to echo it (this is what the_field() do), as I just need the function to return the content + the link I add at the end.

Comment: Try using `get_post_meta($post_id, 'spec-file', true)` instead.

Comment: Is it the correct form id? Form id 1? gform_notification_{$form_id}

Comment: Try this 

`global $post;
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'spec-file', true);`